# React-Style, Webpack, React - Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: The `style` prop

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting the following error in my browser:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

This is when running webpack-dev-server and going to localhost:8080.

./modules/main.js:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');
var HoverAction = require('./HoverAction/HoverAction');

var Application = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HoverAction title="favorite" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

./modules/HoverAction/HoverActions.js:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
'use strict';

var StyleSheet = require('react-style');
var React = require('react');

var HoverActionStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    normal: {
        height: '200px',
        width: '200px',
        border: '1px solid black'        
    }
});

var HoverActionTitleStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    normal: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: '10px'        
    }
});

var HoverAction = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div style={HoverActionStyles.normal}>
                <div ></div>
                <div style={HoverActionTitleStyle.normal} >{this.props.title}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = HoverAction;
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

var ReactStylePlugin = require('react-style-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  entry: './modules/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, 
        loaders: [
          ReactStylePlugin.loader(),
          'jsx-loader?harmony'
        ]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.less$/, 
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader')
//        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      } // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ReactStylePlugin('bundle.css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        // To enable production mode:
        // NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-howto-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.12.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "less": "^2.5.0",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "react-style": "^0.5.5",
    "react-style-webpack-plugin": "0.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "webpack": "^1.8.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.2",
    "react-router": "^0.13.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: you can find answer by following this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44733640/5934465

Answer (score 20, accepted):

React Style requires you to use the `styles` prop instead of `style`.

```
var HoverAction = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div styles={HoverActionStyles.normal}>
                <div ></div>
                <div styles={HoverActionTitleStyle.normal} >{this.props.title}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I used the style attribute in JSX file like this

```
style={{textTransform: 'uppercase'}}
```

and it worked for me

Comment: You can also set up an object like `style={cssLikeStyleObj}`. Notice that you only need a single set of curlies and still no quotes. Quotes is what causes the error in the OP.