# React inline style - style prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to set inline styles in my React application. In this case, for a span:

```
<span className="myClass" style={{float : 'left', paddingRight : '5px'}} > </span>
```

React tells me:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from
>   style properties to values, not a string. For example,
>   style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX. This DOM node
>   was rendered by `SentenceView

I am not quite sure what it means.

PS: I have tried different versions, so I did `paddingRight: 5` as well as `paddingRight: 5 + 'px'` as well as `paddingRight : 5px`, but I didn't have any success!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use "**style**<strike>s</strike>" prop instead of style

```
<span className="myClass" style={{float : 'left', paddingRight : '5px'}} > </span>
```

Here is a great reference from W3Schools which also shows you how to create an object with styling information, and refer to it in the style attribute:
[reference for how to style React using CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp)

Comment: styles is not a valid jsx attribute...how did this work out?

Comment: agree with comment above, tried styles and it did not work but if i do, 'style' it works.  Not sure why this is selected as the answer

Comment: @mohsinulhaq Are you using CSS Modules? If so, then you need `className={myStyles}`, not `styles={myStyles}`. CSS Modules automatically transforms your style objects into a className string.

Comment: This might seem to work but its not actually working. It is not applying these styles with "styles" attribute even though your app will now compile without throwing error. You can even put any invalid name in place of style and your app will compile but you will notice that the intended styles are not being applied. Below you can see Kanishk Verma's answer which explains JSX vs HTML syntax.

Answer (score 35):

There some ways to set style for React Components.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

1. using `style={css_object}` or `style={{color: this.props.color}}`
2. using `className="your-class-name"`

### React REPL

https://jscomplete.com/repl

### 1 style Object

```js
// <span style={styles}>

const styles = {
    color: "red",
    background: "#0f0",
    fontSize: "32px"
};

const BTN = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
           My name is <button>{props.name}</button>
           <hr/>
           I'm <span style={styles}>{props.age}</span> yeas old!
        </div>
    );
};

const infos = {
    name: "xgqfrms",
    age: 23
};

ReactDOM.render(<BTN {...infos} />, mountNode);




// <span style={{color: styles.color}}>

const styles = {
    color: "red",
    background: "#0f0",
    fontSize: "32px"
};

const BTN = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
           My name is <button>{props.name}</button>
           <hr/>
           I'm <span style={{color: styles.color}}>{props.age}</span> yeas old!
        </div>
    );
};

const infos = {
    name: "xgqfrms",
    age: 23
};

ReactDOM.render(<BTN {...infos} />, mountNode);
```

### 2 className & `stylesheet.css`

```js
import './styles.css';

/*
.classname-color{
    color: "red";
    background: "#0f0";
}
*/


const BTN = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            My name is <button>{props.name}</button>
            <hr/>
            I'm <span className="classname-color">{props.age}</span> yeas old!
        </div>
    );
};

const infos = {
    name: "xgqfrms",
    age: 23
};

ReactDOM.render(<BTN {...infos} />, mountNode);
```

```css
.classname-color{
    color: "red";
    background: "#0f0";
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921093/react-style-webpack-react-uncaught-error-invariant-violation-the-style-p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448253/how-to-using-es6-arrow-function-to-realize-immediately-invoked-function-expressi?noredirect=1#comment78072726_40448253

Answer (score 17):

JSX and HTML are different. See [the graphic below from Udemy](http://udemy.com/course/react-redux/learn/lecture/12531454#overview):
[image: Difference between JSX and HTML]

In HTML it is

```html
<div style="background-color: red;"></div>
```

In JSX you write

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}></div>
```

Conditional inline formatting are different in both.

Comment: Did you make the graphics yourself? If not, please share your source!

Comment: The graphics is from the udemy course : https://www.udemy.com/course/react-redux/learn/lecture/12531454#overview  
By stephan Grinder

Answer (score 4):

This is the way how you can define and use inline style with react.

```
/**
 * Style definitions.
 */
const STYLE = {
    infoColor: {
        color: 'green'
    },
    warningColor: {
        color: 'orange'
    },
    errorColor: {
        color: 'red'
    }
};

/**
 * Component
 */
class Welcome extends React.Component {

    /**
     * Rendering into the DOM.
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 style={STYLE.infoColor}>Welcome!</h2>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

when we use inline styling in react we should always use `style={{styleproperties}}`

**Error:**

```
<input style="margin:0 15px 0 0"/>
```

**Solution:**

```
<input style={{margin:"0 15px 0 0"}}/>
```

Comment: this was a decent answer, I needed @dattebayo's answer more though because they are demonstrating the correct syntax for handling multiple properties in the styling attribute

Answer (score 0):

don't wrap the {{}} in double quotes or string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do with inline styling, try to write only width inside your JSX without style Like this:

```
 <img src="./your-image.png" width="40px" />
```