# Right aligning table cell when using React

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to right align the content of a table cell, similar to what is explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp):

```
<td style="text-align:right">
```

However, it seems React has decided that the style keyword should not be used like that:

```
Line XX:  Style prop value must be an object   react/style-prop-object
```

[An answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43366134/214742) indicated that "styles" should be used instead:

```
<td styles="text-align:right">
```

Of course React thinks that is fine but it is not like my web browser knows that when I say `styles` I in fact mean `style`. How can I right align the contents in my table?

Comment: I'm surprised to see that post. The post is absolutely misleading to people. You should use style not styles.

Answer (score 4):

Correct usage is

```
<td style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>
```

[Reference](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your table tag,

---

`<table class="text-center">
</table>`